# How to convert more than two <br/> tag to a double <br/><br/> in php

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

Do not convert

```
<br/>
<br/><br/>
```

Convert, if there are more than two newline tag

```
<br/><br/><br/>
```

into

```
<br/><br/>
```

How to add my condition to this?

```
preg_replace("/(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+/", "<br/><br/>", $input);
```

Comment: What's the significance of not converting three tags if there's a newline in between?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(<br[ ]*\/?>){2,}
```

Simply use this.And replace it by `<br/><br/>`.

Comment: Why Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '{' ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the metacharacter `{min,max}` after the regex will help you.

The [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) actually does a really good job, also the [regex.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `\h` instead of space where `\h`  matches all type of horizontal spaces.

```
preg_replace('~(<br\h*\/?>){2,}~', '<br/><br/>', $string);
```